# Como pegar parte da string a partir do tamanho de uma palavra?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Estou querendo pegar apenas o nome da disciplina de um h1 contendo o seguinte texto: "ENF N1A METODOLOGIA DA PESQUISA CIENTÍFICA (MES)". No caso o que me interessa nessa string é o valor "METODOLOGIA DA PESQUISA CINENTÍFICA". A ideia que eu tive foi usar regex pra retornar essa valor pegando texto a partir do conjunto de strings que fosse maior que x. Alguém poderia dizer se esse é o melhor caminho?

**[ADD]**
Os nomes completos das disciplinas seguem o seguinte padrão:

[cod_dis)][" "][turma][" "][nome_disciplina][" "][(cod_filial)]

Nesse caso, para os exemplos citados eu marquei em itálico a parte que eu gostaria de pegar do todo:

ENF N1A *METODOLOGIA DA PESQUISA CIENTÍFICA* (MES)
ENF N1A *INFORMÁTICA APLICADA* (MES)
ENF N1A *INGLÊS INSTRUMENTAL* (MES)

Ficaria assim:

METODOLOGIA DA PESQUISA CIENTÍFICA
INFORMÁTICA APLICADA
INGLÊS INSTRUMENTAL

P.S. Eu sei que que antes da disciplina existe o código da turma que possui no máximo 4 caracteres, e depois da disciplina, existe o (cod_filial) que sempre fica entre parênteses.

Comment: Somente `METODOLOGIA DA PESQUISA CIENTÍFICA`? Ou alguma outra regra para uma lista de nomes e que possui algum padrão?

Comment: Esse exemplo ficou um pouco vago. Sugiro dar mais exemplos de mais capturas que quer fazer, para se tornar mais clara a regra que está a aplicar

Comment: Gostaria de usar essa mesma regra para buscar o nome das demais disciplinas. Editei a pergunta adicionando mais detalhes. Obg.

Comment: A regex que eu fiz é muito parecida com a da resposta, veja a [demo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qsWg2f/1). Não vou postar pois a resposta já está muito boa.

Comment: Vou olhar sim.  Muito obrigado @danieltakeshi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baseado nos padrões informados, uma regex que pode ser utilizada é a `/([^ ]{1,4} [^ ]{1,4} )([^(]+)( \([^)]+\))/g`. Exemplo:

```js
var text = [
  'ENF N1A METODOLOGIA DA PESQUISA CIENTÍFICA (MES)',
  'ENF N1A INFORMÁTICA APLICADA (MES)',
  'ENF N1A INGLÊS INSTRUMENTAL (MES)'
];

var subtext = [];

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  var exec = /([^ ]{1,4} [^ ]{1,4} )([^(]+)( \([^)]+\))/g.exec(text[i]);
  subtext.push(exec ? exec[2] : null);
}

var $output = document.getElementById("output");

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  var $h1 = document.createElement('h2');
  $h1.innerHTML = text[i];
  $output.append($h1);
}

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = subtext[i];
  $output.append(p);
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Caramba jovem! Deu até vontade de chorar.  Era isso mesmo que eu procurava. Muito obrigado @Diego